# Errror when trying to display SQL data from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to graph in canvasjs

Tags: php, sqlsrv, canvasjs

Heres the code:

I tried converting the code from mysql to mysqlsrv which has been a mess. I need to display values from the database onto a graph.

```
<?php
 require 'conn.php';
$dataPoints = array();
try{
     
    $link = $conn;

    $handle = "select Lolo_Setpoint, Hihi_Setpoint from Alarms";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$handle);
    
     
     
   
    foreach ((array) $result as $row)   
    {
        array_push($dataPoints, array("x"=> $row[0], "y"=> $row[1]));
    }
    $link = null;
}
catch(\PDOException $ex){
    print($ex->getMessage());
}
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
<script>
window.onload = function () {
 
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    theme: "light1", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
    title:{
        text: "PHP Column Chart from Database"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc  
        dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
    }]
});
chart.render();
 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is just a blank screen

Comment: Management Studio is the graphical tool you can use to connect to SQL Server. And there is no "mysqlsrv". You either mean MySQL or SQL Server (or sqlsrv, if it's the php module)

Comment: thanks for the clarification, im just starting out and i need help with sqlsrv